# NPM Stopped Working - Unsafe Perm in Lifecycle

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

My clone of reactboilerplate.com stopped working suddenly, so I tried to reclone it into a new repo to see if I can troubleshoot the issue. I tried doing `npm install -verbose` in both and it came back with the errors listed below. The weird thing is, I can clone the same repo on a virtual box, and npm install works just fine. I also tried to clear the npm cache, but no result after. Any ideas ? [image]

package.json file: https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/package.json

Comment: I don't see any errors?

Comment: isn't the "unsafe-perm in lifecycle" a error ? Basically, I can't npm install anything. Not even from a clean repo

Comment: No that seems to me like a normal verbose output. Can you post your package.json?

Comment: https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/package.json

Comment: I end up having to install 1 by 1

Comment: Can you try to execute `npm run setup`? EDIT: And maybe try to update npm.

Comment: whats the command to update npm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151435/discussion-between-puelo-and-justin-e-samuels).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when you run it in docker it runs as root when you run in virtualbox it is likely running as a non-root user. There is some silliness going on about `unsafe-perm` setting that it either changes from `true` to `false` when running as root or just behaves differently. Here is a reference to an article that suggests setting `npm config set unsafe-perm true` and attempts to explain what is going on:

https://geedew.com/What-does-unsafe-perm-in-npm-actually-do/

This condition may be triggered by any dependency, so your builds can fail at any time if you don't freeze them.